after upgrade scripts on checkout not loading
After I upgrade to magento 2.4.7-p1, on checkout page scripts are not loading.
On any other page the url from requirejs is
https://app.exampleproject.test/static/frontend/Mgs/claue_child/pl_PL/jquery.js
but for some reason on checkout page same url is bad
https://app.exampleproject.test/polish/checkout/jquery.js
I try clear cache, flush it. Also i remove var folders ect.
What might be reason or how can i debug source of problem ?

you need to check the new CSP https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/experience-platform/tags/client-side/content-security-policy
it will "report" on every page, but block the content on checkout pages
